# Using instance methods in the app delegate

Tags: ios, methods, instance, appdelegate

I wanted to run a instance method from my BPGameController class called "pauseGame" in my app delegate when my application enters background mode and when it resigns, and a instance method called "resumeGame" when the application becomes active again, I've tried a few different things but none have worked for me so far

Comment: Get a reference to the existing `BPGameController` instance and call the method.

Comment: Why are you doing this from the app delegate? Setup your controller to respond to the associated notifications instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BPGameController's viewDidLoad method sign up for the notifications as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pauseGame)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resumeGame)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

When you are done remove yourself from observing.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: You left out the really important part of this answer. You must remove the observer in the `dealloc` method or the app will likely crash at some point.

Comment: i have added it for a more complete answer.